# NSMetadataQuery returns files which apparently don't exist

Tags: ios, icloud

I've recently start integrating iCloud functionality into an application. I have 2 test spreadsheets which worked correctly when uploaded to iCloud through my application (for test purposes). Now when I drop more spreadsheets into the appropriate iCloud application folder that now appears in my Mac's Finder window, the application sees the files as hidden and they can't be read.

Can anyone tell me why these files are being saved as hidden files? How I can prevent this from happening. My app needs the ability to read the CSV files placed into the iCloud application folder from any of my Apple devices (or Windows using the iCloud for Windows software).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After no help from the Apple documentation I managed to find some forums that explain these hidden files mean it hasn't yet been downloaded. I guess the metadata for the files is downloaded first to show they exist, but only upon request will the files actually be downloaded.

In my code, if the file is hidden I simple make a call to begin the download:

`bool downloading = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:[result valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey] error:&error];`

This will start downloading the file that the NSMetadataQuery returned and will return a boolean value if starting it was successful. At this point I just pop up an alert to let the user know its downloading and to try again in a few seconds (small files so it general only takes a few). In the future I may try and implement a download progress or wait screen, but for now it does the job.